# relocation and symbol table value

Tags: c

I have main.c file which contains call to external function fun()

```
int main()
{
 fun();
}
```

and result of readelf -r is as follows

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x298 contains 3 entries:
Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name +Addend
00000000000a  000b00000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 fun - 4
```

I just want to know that  how info field(which is symbol table entry) is mapped with symbol fun and why sym.value is 0000??

Comment: Do you call `readelf` on the object file? When the symbol `fun` haven't been resolved by the linker yet?

Comment: yes i have called readelf on object file object files are not created by linker..Linker just links that object files so we can create object file of above code and it will give result of readelf as shown in my question

Comment: Object files are not complete, they represent a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) basically. Symbols defined elsewhere simply can not be resolved, therefore you have a zero value for such functions.

Comment: thanks for your clarification  but what is info field and how it is mapped to symbol able entry ??

Comment: This question actually has very little to do with C. You could have similar testcases in virtually any other language, and the output would vary similarly from system to system. Unfortunately, there are no *other* tags present. Hence, I think it might be best to *add new tags (and delete the C tag)* or *close this question* because as it currently stands, it's unlikely to be *found* by future visitors who are looking for it, and consequently unlikely to be *useful* to such future visitors. I'm not aware of any more suitable tags, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a fundamental indexing problem which makes this question unlikely to be found useful to anyone in the future

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the C standard doesn't *actually* specify how this works under the covers, the description that follows is of a very common implementation method.

---

With a single translation unit holding the code:

```
int main() { fun(); }
```

the information available from that compiled (not yet linked) object file is basically:

```
symbol  status   value
------  ------   -----
main    defined  pointer to main within object
fun     needed   zero
```

That's because it *knows* where `main` is but has no information on `fun` - it will need to be found later. So reading the object file will naturally return an unknown value for `fun`.

Of course, you will need some code to define `fun` as well, such as in another translation unit:

```
void fun(void) { puts("Hello, world."); }
```

Compiling *this* would result in the following information:

```
symbol  status   value
------  ------   -----
fun     defined  pointer to fun within object
puts    needed   zero
```

It's the *link* stage that ties these together. It takes *both* object files (and the object/library files for the any other dependencies, such as the C run-time library containing `puts`) and binds them together, making adjustments to all code that uses undefined symbols.

So what you end up with an executable file format where all symbols are known and all references are resolved.